# Represent blocked messages with msc package

Tags: msc

I am using the `msc` package to include protocols in a document.
I would like to have something like the following sequence chart,
but with `m1` stopped before reaching `B`.
[image]
I did not find any related questions, and on the package documentation
I only found the `stop` command to stop instances, but not messages.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this using the `msc` package, if possible?

EDIT: here is the code I used to produce the simple protocol above (without the parts used to change width, etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{msc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
            \begin{msc}{a protocol}

                \declinst{a}{}{A}   
                \declinst{b}{}{B}   
                \declinst{c}{}{C}

                \mess{$m_1$}{a}{b}
                \nextlevel  
                \mess{$m_1'$}{c}{b}
                \nextlevel[2]
                \mess{other messages}{a}{c}
                \mess{}{c}{a}
                \nextlevel[2]

            \end{msc}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Which version of the package are you using, the one on CTAN based on PSTricks, or the development version based on TikZ?

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you could add the code for that diagram, makes it a lot more convenient for those trying to help.

Comment: ... related informations about minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The package version should be the CTAN one

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for pointing this out, I included a MWE without the details needed to format the width, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some rummaging in the package code:

[image]

I defined a new macro `\messstop`, used similarly to `\mess`, i.e.

```
\messstop{$m_1$}{a}{b}
```

It has an optional argument to set the distance from `b` where the line stops, e.g. with

```
\messstop[20pt]{$m_1$}{a}{b}
```

it stops 20pt before `b` instead of the default (which I set to `10pt`).

---

Some explanation:

In the definition of `\messstop` I add a (local) patch to the macro that draws the message arrow in the first place, to remove the arrow tip specification. I don't know if this is the best method, but it's fairly concise, and it works.

You'll see that in `\messstop` I call `\mess` with two extra bracketed arguments in the end: `\mess{#2}{#3}{#4}[0][#1]`. The `[0]` indicates that this is a message where the sender and receiver is not the same. Specifically it means that `\mess@leveloffset` becomes zero. The second bracket pair is where the distance from `b` is inserted (i.e. the optional argument to `\messstop`, mentioned above). In the package, this length is used to set the `\mess@instanceoffset` length.

Finally, I call a macro `\drawcross`, which I defined based on the `\stop` macro in `msc.sty`. It draws a cross at the current y-level, at the x-position defined by the mandatory argument. E.g. `\drawcross{a}` draws a cross at the x-position of the `a` instance. Like `\messstop`, this has an optional argument used to define the (negative) offset in the x-direction, so `\drawcross[10pt]{a}` would move the cross 10pt to the left.

To make this work regardless of the direction of the arrow, I added an `\ifthenelse` which tests the x-position of sender and receiver, and changes the sign of the offset passed to `\drawcross` accordingly.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\makeatletter
\newcommand\drawcross[2][0pt]{%
    % adapted from the definition of \stop in msc.sty
    \setlength{\tmp@Yb}{\msc@currentheight}%
    \setlength{\tmp@X}{\msc@instxpos{#2}}%
    \addtolength{\tmp@X}{-#1}
    \setlength{\tmp@Xa}{\tmp@X-0.3\stopwidth}%
    \setlength{\tmp@Xb}{\tmp@X+0.3\stopwidth}%
    \setlength{\tmp@Ya}{\tmp@Yb+0.3\stopwidth}%
    \setlength{\tmp@Yb}{\tmp@Yb-0.3\stopwidth}%
    \psline(\tmp@Xa,-\tmp@Ya)(\tmp@Xb,-\tmp@Yb)%
    \psline(\tmp@Xb,-\tmp@Ya)(\tmp@Xa,-\tmp@Yb)%
}

\newcommand\messstop[4][10pt]{%
    {%group to keep patching local 
    \patchcmd{\msc@drawnonselfarrow}{{->}}{}{}{} % remove arrow tip spec from \psline
    \mess{#2}{#3}{#4}[0][#1] % draw message
    }
    % need to find out the relative position of sender and receiver
    % if sender is leftmost, use positive offset in \drawcross
    % else, use negative offset
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\msc@instxpos{#3} < \msc@instxpos{#4}}}%
    {\drawcross[#1]{#4}} % 
    {\drawcross[-#1]{#4}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \begin{msc}{a protocol}

                \declinst{a}{}{A}   
                \declinst{b}{}{B}   
                \declinst{c}{}{C}

                \messstop[20pt]{$m_1$}{a}{b}
                \nextlevel  
                \mess{$m_1'$}{c}{b}
                \nextlevel[2]
                \mess{other messages}{a}{c}
                \mess{}{c}{a}
                \nextlevel[2]

            \end{msc}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for, perfect solution and explanation.